# How to permanently pass a value to view until user closes browser? MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling

When welcome page gets refreshed the value i tempData gets Lost. I have applied a check on user login (admin login) and hide / show an element accordingly. For example if user type is 1 (global admin) is shows 'admin management' link on welcome page otherwise it hides it. I am working with tempData to store the 'Type' it works as expected on login but if I refresh Welcome page it raises this error: Please Help
[image: Upon REFRESH]

> My Logic

```
public ActionResult Login()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your Login page.";

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(tbl_Admin adminObj)
        { 
            studentDBEntities db = new studentDBEntities();
            var adminvar = db.tbl_Admin.Where(x => x.Email == adminObj.Email && x.Password == adminObj.Password).FirstOrDefault();
            
            if (adminvar != null)
            {
                if (adminvar.Type== true)
                {
                    TempData["IsGlobalAdmin"] = true;
                    return RedirectToAction("Welcome");
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["IsGlobalAdmin"] = false;
                    return RedirectToAction("Welcome");
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
        public ActionResult Welcome()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome Admin - Admin Account Page";
            return View();
        }
```

> my view

```
@model IEnumerable<StudentReg.tbl_Admin>
<div class="well">
    <center><h4><b>Navigate To: </b></h4></center>
    @if ((bool)TempData["IsGlobalAdmin"])
    {
        <center><p>@Html.ActionLink("Admin Management", "ListAdmin")</p></center>
    }
    <center><p>@Html.ActionLink("Student Management", "ListStudent")</p></center>
</div>
```

Comment: You can declar a string for example in a module, and assign him your needed value, that you can access in your view by putting the following line: ViewData("Username") = yourString ...  

but actually for test is fine but I would not really suggest, because you have to handle also the logout... are you using .session for your log in ? if so you can put this code in your view this CS code : ViewData("Username") = HttpContext.Current.Session("Username");  if you need answer how to use this log in method let me know I will put it as answer.

Comment: The TempData value holds its value only after one RedirectToAction

Comment: @B.S. I simply want to display hide some elements according to the user type. I am new to mvc and asp.net so I don't have clear understanding of certain things